# What exactly does f: R->R or f:Z->R mean in discrete math?

Tags: set, discrete-mathematics

I came across a topic that I'm not too familiar with. It asks for whether a certain function f(x)=1/(x^2-2) defines a function f: R->R and f:Z->R.

What is the question asking for? The topic is discrete mathematics.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about discrete mathematics, which is more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I wonder why a math question is here that has no relation to programming...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Discrete [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 5):

The notation f : A → B means "f is a function whose domain is A and whose codomain is B." Intuitively, this means that f takes as input an element of A and produces an output that's an element of B.

In C, for example, this would be like the function prototype

```
B f(A);
```

This just says that f takes in an A and returns a B, with the actual way that f performs the transformation not specified.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

These are common math notations.
http://www.solving-math-problems.com/math-symbols-set-special.html

f: R->R  means when you plug in a real number for x you will get back a real number.
f: Z->R  mean when you plug in an integer you will get back a real number.

These notations are used in advance math topics to help analyze the nature of the math equation rather than getting stuck on numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#myfirstpostinStackOverflow
```

The above answers are very formal answers, and what I would've given had I answered it first.

Considering that OP is reading about discrete math, I'll offer this heuristic, not necessarily rigorous but good enough.

If a function has the set of real numbers as its domain, then it's possible that we may be dealing with a **continuous** structure. On the other hand, if a function has the set of integers as its domain, we're dealing with a **discrete** structure.

If you graph the function f defined by f(n) = n, where n is an integer, it looks like a diagonal line passing through the origin, but instead of a straight line, it's a set of points.

Going back, this function f is f: Z ----> Z. It has domain Z and codomain Z.

It also satisfies the dictionary definition of **discrete**.

> **dis·crete** dəˈskrēt/ adjective individually separate and distinct.